# Populate dynamic dropdown list with jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

This is my first time asking something here. Also, I'm learning to use JS, so I'm trying to make a dynamic dropdown list that depends of another value chosen in another dropdown. The problem is that when I choose a value for the first dropdown, I get invisible fields in the second dropdown (and these fields don't match the number of options I have). I have tried to solve the problem, but I don't know what to do. An important thing is that my code is based on another code from http://highoncoding.com/Articles/770_Implementing_Dynamic_DropDownList_in_ASP_NET_MVC_3_Framework.aspx

Profile Model:

```
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please provide your name")]
        [Display(Name = "Name")]
        public string name { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please provide your lastname")]
        [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
        public string lastName { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Birthdate")]
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        public string birthDate { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Age")]
        public int age { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please provide the city where you live")]
        [Display(Name = "City")]
        public string addressCity { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please provide the country where you live")]
        [Display(Name = "Country")]
        public string addressCountry { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Hobbies")]
        public string hobbies { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Languages")]
        public string languages { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please provide your e-mail")]
        [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
        [Display(Name = "Email")]
        public string email { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please provide your mobile number")]
        [Display(Name = "Mobile")]
        public string mobile { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter your job title")]
        [Display(Name = "Job")]
        public string job { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Member rank")]
        public string memberRank { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Points")]
        public int points { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please describe your skills")]
        [Display(Name = "Skills")]
        public string skills { get; set; }

        public int articleCount { get; set; }

        public List<SelectListItem> ProfileList { get; set; }

        private List<SelectListItem> categories = new List<SelectListItem>();
        private List<SelectListItem> values = new List<SelectListItem>();

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select a category")]

        public string selectedCategory { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select a category")]

        public string selectedValue { get; set; }




        public List<SelectListItem> ValuesList
        {
            get { return values;  }
        }

        public List<SelectListItem> CategoryList
        {
            get
            {
                categories.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "Country", Value = "1" });
                categories.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "Skills", Value = "2" });
                categories.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "Languages", Value = "3" });
                categories.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "Hobbies", Value = "4" });
                return categories;

            }
        }


    }
```

Profile Controller:

```
        {
            return View(new ProfileModel());
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Report(ProfileModel smodel)
        {
            return View();
        }

        public string GetValuesCategory(string id)
        {
            //get the products from the repository
            var products = new List<SelectListItem>();

            if(id == "1")
            {
                products.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "Costa Rica", Value = "1" });
                products.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "Mexico", Value = "2" });
            }

            else if (id == "2")
            {
                products.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "Networking", Value = "1" });
                products.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "DataBases", Value = "2" });
            }

            else if(id == "3")
            {
                products.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "English", Value = "1" });
                products.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "Italian", Value = "2" });
            }
            else if(id == "4")
            {
                products.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "Sports", Value = "1" });
                products.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "Movies", Value = "2" });
            }
            return new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(products);
        }
```

Finally, my Report view is:

````
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>Create Article</h4>
    <hr />
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <label class="control-label col-md-2"></label> @ViewBag.Message
        </div>
    </div>

    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    @*<div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>*@



    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.selectedCategory, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.selectedCategory, new SelectList(Model.CategoryList, "Value", "Text"), "--Please select a topic--", new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.selectedCategory, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.selectedValue, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.selectedValue, new SelectList(Model.ValuesList, "Value", "Text"), "--Please select a topic--", new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.selectedValue, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
}

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#selectedCategory").change(function () {
            var url = '@Url.Action("GetValuesCategory", "Profile")';
            var data = { id: $(this).val() };
            $.get(url, data,
                function (values) {


                    var ddlSelectedValue = $("#selectedValue");
                    ddlSelectedValue.empty()

                    //populate products
                    for (i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {

                        $("<option/>").val(values[i].Value).text(values[i].Text).appendTo("#ValuesList");
                    }
                });
        });
    });
</script>```
````

Comment: My advice is to isolate the problem to only the javascript part of it. You could try to reproduce it in https://jsfiddle.net/ for example with static html, an hardcoded/mocked response and your callback function. If you still can't work it out, you can then share the fiddle and I'm sure you'll find someone that will have a play with it and find the problem. Also you've posted a lot of code, keep in mind that many contributors may not have enough time on their hands to go through all of that, so if you only post the most relevant parts you'll be more likely to find an answer :)

Comment: Is your change handler getting called?   Is your get success function getting called?   There's also an error parameter function...add some console statements or use Javascript debugger